# Python ctypes 'segmentation fault: 11'

Tags: python, c, ctypes, heap-memory, stack-memory

**EDIT:**
New example that explode without changing the ulimit, and it does not matter what is in the c part.

I am a python user (I learned from an edX course), and I have been working with ctypes and c (but I dont really know c).
I have a "Segmentation fault: 11" problem with my code when I run it with some specific parameters (basically, a big array size), here is a small example that replicates what my code do:

test1.py:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import ctypes as cy


Lib_Path = './lib.so'

class Simulacion:
    def __init__(self, ss,tm):
        self.tm    = tm;
        self.ss    = ss;

    def ejecutar(self):
        self.data   = np.empty((int(self.ss), self.tm), dtype = float)
        lib   = cy.CDLL(Lib_Path)
        dblc = cy.c_double; pntrc = ndpointer(dblc);  intc = cy.c_long
        lib.trisolve.argtypes = [intc, pntrc, intc]
        lib.trisolve(self.tm, self.data, self.ss)
        return self.data

ss = 10
tm  = int(1e6);

sim = Simulacion(ss,tm)
data = sim.ejecutar()
```

test1.c

```
void trisolve(int tm, double* data, int ss){

}
```

makefile

```
SRC=test1
GCC=gcc-6
all:
    $(GCC) -fPIC -fopenmp -lm -c -O3 $(SRC).c
    $(GCC) -shared -lgomp -o lib.so $(SRC).o
clean:
    rm lib.so
    rm $(SRC).o
```

This code explode without changing the ulimit.

for my real code, i am using "ulimit -s 65532" which is the maximum stack size in my mac. This limit the size of the arrays that I am using, and currently I need to duplicate the size of it.
For what I have found, the problem is that the arrays are being stored in the stack instead of the heap, so I have this hard limit due to the SO.
So my question is, how I can pass that big array to C, store it in the heap and then bring it back to python ?

I mostly use python, and the c part of the code I did it without a good formation in this lenguaje, so "stacks", "heap" and probably "malloc" are new terms for me.

Thanks!

Comment: "but I dont really know c" - well, you should probably go learn it. You're trying to do something moderately advanced, but you're making basic errors like mixing up `int` and `long`, let alone the more complex parts of working with NumPy arrays in C.

Comment: I really don't need to learn it more that what I already know (except for what i am asking here). since I am using c only to solve a matrix (since is much faster than python) probably I can make mayor edition to the code and bypass my problem, but I want to know how to fix the code like it is now. thanks.

Comment: "I am using c only to solve a matrix" - what, as in solving systems of linear equations? [NumPy has that built in](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html), and it'll already automatically delegate to LAPACK.

Comment: As written this isn't using the stack to store the array. It's allocated on the heap, and then you iterate over it. I don't see why `omp parallel for` would cause that problem either. But CPython itself needs at least 32K of stack.

Comment: Is more complex than that, but I don't want to explain everything here xD, in the code I have a big `while`, inside it a few `for` to set the terms of the matrix, then the solution of it, then some modification of the result, and then the iteration again.
@eryksun if is not using the stack, why when I use `ulimit -s 16`, I got a segmentation fault, but if I set it to, for example, 65532, the code works without a problem?. the `omp parallel for` is not the problem here, the program doesn't even start running the c code. (if I put `print` there, the segmentation fault occurs before it).

Comment: `ulimit -s 16` causes Python to fail no matter what. It's not enough stack for the interpreter. It needs a bit more than 32 KiB.

Comment: I will try to make an example that have a bigger `ulimit`, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Done, the new example explodes without setting the `ulimit` and does not depend on what is in the c code.

Comment: `np.empty((int(self.ss), self.tm), dtype = float)` creates an array object on the heap, and the ctypes call passes a pointer to the data. It's not storing the data on the stack, which would be a crazy thing to do. Something else is causing a segfault. I wish I could say what that is, but your code worked fine for me.

Comment: Really?  Because in my mac it explodes.  And in the cluster in my university also dies unless I change ulimit.  Can you try again but with tm =1e7 or 1e8? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem, which had nothing to do with ctypes.
Inside my real c code, I defined an array with `array[tm]`, but `tm` was to big for the stack.
Why I was able to replicate the problem with the code above? I really don't know, but when I tried today (since @eryksun told that the code worked for him) it did not exploded.
Thanks for the help; I will try to learn a bit more of C in the future.

Comment: If you declared that array as an automatic variable, then it does use the stack. To use the heap you need to `malloc` memory, which returns a `void *` pointer. In this case, to prevent memory leaks you have to carefully control the return paths of the function to ensure that you `free` the pointer.